# Do I need to install something else besides Spark release package?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

There seems to be two ways to install Spark.

1. When installing Spark by downloading prebuilt Spark release  (e.g. spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz) from    https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html,

   - do I need to  additionally install  `java` command, by  installing JRE?
   - Do I  need to  additionally install java compiler `javac` by installing JDK?
   - Do I need to  additionally install scala compiler? (I guess no, because I saw the downloaded Spark release contains
     `./jar/scala-compiler.jar`.)
   - Do I need to  additionally install pyspark?  (I guess no, because I saw the downloaded Spark release contains `./bin/pyspark`.)
2. When installing Spark by running `pip install pyspark`, does it
   already install spark for Java and for Scala? Or do I need to
   additionally install some things in order to program Spark
   applications in Java and Scala?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://spark.apache.org/faq.html

> do I need to additionally install java command, by installing JRE?

yes see the faq.

> Do I need to additionally install java compiler javac by installing JDK?

no. i guess no, but i always use sdk.

> Do I need to additionally install scala compiler? (I guess no, because I saw the downloaded Spark release contains ./jar/scala-compiler.jar.)

no

> Do I need to additionally install pyspark? (I guess no, because I saw the downloaded Spark release contains ./bin/pyspark.)

no

> When installing Spark by running pip install pyspark, does it already install spark for Java and for Scala?

yes.

```
tree .venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/bin
.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/bin
├── beeline
├── beeline.cmd
├── docker-image-tool.sh
├── find-spark-home
├── find-spark-home.cmd
├── load-spark-env.cmd
├── load-spark-env.sh
├── pyspark
├── pyspark.cmd
├── pyspark2.cmd
├── run-example
├── run-example.cmd
├── spark-class
├── spark-class.cmd
├── spark-class2.cmd
├── spark-shell
├── spark-shell.cmd
├── spark-shell2.cmd
├── spark-sql
├── spark-sql.cmd
├── spark-sql2.cmd
├── spark-submit
├── spark-submit.cmd
├── spark-submit2.cmd
├── sparkR
├── sparkR.cmd
└── sparkR2.cmd
```

> Or do I need to additionally install some things in order to program Spark applications in Java and Scala?

to program in scala you need to install scala to actually create the application jar.

i think use the downloaded release is easier to migrate to run things in the cluster.